# Loop over results with Oracle Database

Tags: python, oracle

I want to iterate over a result in cx_Oracle.

My query is:

```
select * from table
```

How can I do it in a simple way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the cursor iterator:

```
curs.execute('SELECT * from `TABLE`')
for row in curs:
    print row
```

---

You can use `fetchall()` to get all rows at once.

```
for row in curs.fetchall():
    print row
```

Comment: don't you want to fetch them first ?